# publish/subscribe middleware

Tags: java, publish-subscribe

I am looking for a publish/subscribe middleware written in  Java. On Google Code, there are several middleware , but they are not well documented. So, I am facing difficulties of using those middleware.

your pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ is pub/sub system that simply works. Give it a try, it's well documented and easy to kick.